# mysql selecting a union where values in one don't appear in the other

Tags: mysql, sql

sorry for the poorly titled post.

Say I have the following table:

```
C1 | C2       | c3
1  | foo      | x
2  | bar      | y
2  | blaz     | z
3  | something| y
3  | hello    | z
3  | doctor   | x
4  | name     | y
5  | continue | x
5  | yesterday| z
6  | tomorrow | y
```

I'm trying to come up w/ a sql statement which performs the following union:
1st retrieval retrieves all records w/ c3 = 'y'

2nd retrieval retrieves the first instance of a record where c3 <> 'y' and the result is not in the previous union

So, for the result, I should see:

```
C1 | C2   
1  | foo  
2  | bar 
3  | something
4  | name
5  | continue
6  | tomorrow
```

So two questions:  1:  Am I totally smoking crack where I think I can do this, and 2: (assuming I can), how do I do this?

Comment: Be careful when phrasing a concept for a query that includes statements like "get the first record that..." because SQL is a set-oriented notion, and doesn't really have a "first" concept (although some vendors have grafted on features to create the impression it does :) ) Technically, I don't think you're really guaranteed repeatable ordering in a "pure" SQL query...

Comment: One other observation: Doesn't your first condition imply the second? That is, if the first set is c3='y', and the second is c3<>'y', no records from the second set could possibly be present in the first one...

Comment: by first, I'm assuming two distinct sets:  first set retrieves all items which C3 = 'y', second set retrieves all items where C3 <> 'y' and NOT in the first set.  So in the above example, for item 3, an item has been returned for C1 = 3.

Comment: Guess I'm being hard-headed :) The entire list of records consists either of records where C3='y' or C3<>'y'. First query is for c3='y', second query is for c3<>'y', so how could *any* records in second query have been present in the first query? I'm just not understanding your second selection condition properly, I guess.

Comment: @DavidW: I think that for second query OP wants one of records not having C1 selected in first query.

Comment: Okay, now THAT makes sense, thanks...guess I'm too late to the party anyway, others have given good answers it appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT   a.C1, a.C2
  FROM   MyTable a
 WHERE   a.C3 = 'y'
    UNION
SELECT   b.C1, b.C2
  FROM   MyTable b
 WHERE   b.C3 <> 'y' AND
         b.C1 not in 
            (
               SELECT c.C1
                 FROM MyTable c
                WHERE c.C3 = 'y'
            )
```

**UPDATE 1**

by the way, why is that there is only *one record* of `5` in your desired result? where, in fact, there could be ***two***.

**[SEE FOR DEMO 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d56c6/1)**

OR

```
SELECT g.C1, MIN(g.C2) C2
FROM
(SELECT   a.C1, a.C2
  FROM   MyTable a
 WHERE   a.C3 = 'y'
    UNION
SELECT   b.C1, b.C2
  FROM   MyTable b
 WHERE   b.C3 <> 'y' AND
         b.C1 not in 
            (
               SELECT c.C1
                 FROM MyTable c
                WHERE c.C3 = 'y'
            )
) g
GROUP BY g.C1
```

**[SEE FOR DEMO 2 (yields same result with your desired result)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d56c6/5)**

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f23e/8).

```
select *
  from table1
 where c3 = 'y'
 union all
(select table1.*
  from table1
  left join table1 t1
    on table1.c1 = t1.c1
   and t1.c3 = 'y'
 where table1.c3 <> 'y'
   and t1.c1 is null
 -- The meaning of first becomes clear here
 order by table1.c3, table1.c2
 limit 1)
```

Note: foo is not in a list because it is marked as `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT C1, C2
    FROM   Table1
    Where  C3 = 'y'

    UNION

   (
    SELECT  C1, C2
    FROM  Table1
    Where C3 <> 'y' ORDER BY C1 LIMIT 1
   )
 ORDER BY C1
```